# How to sort list in Django Template form button click?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django View where I get all Expanses from the DB.
I render them in the HTML Template like below.
I want to have a button that is changing the sorting of the items by date on button click.
What is best practise to do so ?

```
// View Snippet
def expanse_list(request):

    #List of all expanses
    expanses_list = Expanse.objects.all()


 // Template Snippet
 {% for expans in expanses %}
     <li class="expanse-card">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either write another view that returns the items in the desired order like this:

```py
expanses_list = Expanse.objects.all().order_by('date')
```

Or even better include an interactive table like [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and let the user click around as they like.